# How to select top N rows in a Linq GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

hope you can help me out here. 
I have a list of Bookings where I would like to get the top 2 rows in each group of TourOperators.

here's a sample of the data:

```
List<Booking> list = new List<Booking>();
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "31111111", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 1), TourOperator = "SPI" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "32222222", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 2), TourOperator = "SPI" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "33333333", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 3), TourOperator = "SPI" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "34444444", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 4), TourOperator = "SPI" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "35555555", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 5), TourOperator = "SPI" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "36666666", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 6), TourOperator = "SPI" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "11111111", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 1), TourOperator = "VIN" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "12222222", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 2), TourOperator = "VIN" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "13333333", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 3), TourOperator = "VIN" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "14444444", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 4), TourOperator = "VIN" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "15555555", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 5), TourOperator = "VIN" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "16666666", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 6), TourOperator = "VIN" });
        list.Add(new Booking() { BookingNo = "17777777", DepDate = new DateTime(2011, 5, 7), TourOperator = "VIN" });
```

I have this Linq, but it only gives me the first Booking in each group:

```
List<Booking> yetAnotherList = list.GroupBy(row => row.TourOperator)
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(row => row.DepDate).First()).ToList();
```

The data I was hoping for was something like this:

31111111, 2011-05-01, SPI
32222222, 2011-05-02, SPI
11111111, 2011-05-01, VIN
12222222, 2011-05-02, VIN

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Replace `First()` with `Take(2)` and use `SelectMany()`:

```
List<Booking> yetAnotherList = 
                 list.GroupBy(row => row.TourOperator)
                     .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(row => row.DepDate).Take(2)) 
                     .ToList();
```

**Update**: Forgot the `SelectMany` the first time. You want to flatten the result (which `SelectMany` does), otherwise you get a list of `IEnumerables`.

Comment: That gives me: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApplication2.Booking>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication2.Booking>'

Comment: JensRud, try to use var and to see in debug what type has yetAnotherList.

Comment: Wow thanks Chris, the combination of SelectMany and Take was just what I needed! The results needed flattening as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `var` and replace `First()` with `Take(2)`:

```
var yetAnotherList = list.GroupBy(row => row.TourOperator)
                  .Select(g => g.OrderBy(row => row.DepDate).Take(2)).ToList();
```

Comment: JensRud told, that he has an exception after replacing First() with Take(2). What do you mean!? I adviced JensRud to use var to have an ability to see more detailed information about result. I sure it will not be exception.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joolio, only it gives me two nested lists, and I need the result to be flattened. SelectMany does this as I have discovered from Chris' answer.

Comment: Should be `Select` replaces with `SelectMany`.