# c# Linq - Select Top 2 from Each Group

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I need to get the Top 2 Products for each ProductTypeName :

```
var productDetails = (from p in products
                            join po in productOrganisations 
                            on p.Id equals po.ProductId
                            where po.OrganisationId == id
                            where p.ProductTypeId == (typeId > 0 ? typeId : p.ProductTypeId) //filter by type if specified
                            where p.IsLive
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = p.Id,
                                Name = p.Name,
                                SupplierName = p.Supplier.Name,
                                ProductTypeName = p.ProductType.Name,
                                ShortDescription = p.ShortDescription,
                                ProductTypeId = p.ProductTypeId,
                                DatePublished = p.DatePublished,
                                CurrencyId = p.CurrencyId,

                            })
                            .AsNoTracking()
                            .ToArray();
```

Currently the above statement returns all my products, hundreds. and each product has a property ProductTypeName .

I need to group by this ProductTypeName and then get the top two IN EACH GROUP by datepublished descending.

Any ideas?

Comment: use the take function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem I ended up solving by using:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.ProductTypeId)
.SelectMany(x => x.Take(2))
```

So the full example would be:

```
var productDetails = (from p in products
                            join po in productOrganisations 
                            on p.Id equals po.ProductId
                            where po.OrganisationId == id
                            where p.ProductTypeId == (typeId > 0 ? typeId : p.ProductTypeId) //filter by type if specified
                            where p.IsLive
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = p.Id,
                                Name = p.Name,
                                SupplierName = p.Supplier.Name,
                                ProductTypeName = p.ProductType.Name,
                                ShortDescription = p.ShortDescription,
                                ProductTypeId = p.ProductTypeId,
                                DatePublished = p.DatePublished,
                                CurrencyId = p.CurrencyId,
                            })
                            .GroupBy(x => x.ProductTypeId)
                            .SelectMany(x => x.Take(2))
                            .AsNoTracking()
                            .ToArray();
```

This works, but I wonder is it the best way? Most efficient?

Answer (score 6):

[ChrisWue provides a good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769948/how-to-select-top-n-rows-in-a-linq-groupby). If this solves your problem shoot him an up vote

Strongly type your list then use `GroupBy`, `OrderBy` and `Take` to get your result.

Strongly type your result set like so:

```
List<ProductDetails> myProductList = (from p in products
                        join po in productOrganisations 
                        on p.Id equals po.ProductId
                        where po.OrganisationId == id
                        where p.ProductTypeId == (typeId > 0 ? typeId : p.ProductTypeId) //filter by type if specified
                        where p.IsLive
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            Name = p.Name,
                            SupplierName = p.Supplier.Name,
                            ProductTypeName = p.ProductType.Name,
                            ShortDescription = p.ShortDescription,
                            ProductTypeId = p.ProductTypeId,
                            DatePublished = p.DatePublished,
                            CurrencyId = p.CurrencyId,

                        })
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .ToList();
```

Then Query the list like this:

```
List<ProductDetail> finalResult = 
                     myProductList.GroupBy(p => p.ProductTypeName)
                     .SelectMany(d => d.OrderBy(r => r.DatePublished.Take(2))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Your solution looks solid. I think it might be missing an 'OrderBy' on the DatePublished.

Comment: This is very useful and correct for many cases, but in my case in the real life scenario I do not strongly type at this point because my result set actually has extra columns purely for storing calculated values, later on I select from these and pass to a strongly types result set.